# How to set or change role upon login automatically in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have an existing `postgres 11` database called `host_db` and we have an existing application called `host_app` that has been using this database for a long time. This service uses superuser `host_app_user` to connect to database and do all the transactions. Hence, all the database objects are owned by this database superuser.

Now, we want to create `db_admin` superuser role too in our database whose credentials will be maintained by `Vault`. But to not mix up database ownership, I was thinking that whenever `db_admin` logs in to the database, it assumes the role of `host_app_user`. That way whatever changes the logged admin does will all be done as `host_app_user`.

My question is: Is there a way I can automatically set the role of logged in user in postgres at the time of logging in?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
alter role db_admin set role host_app_user;
```

`db_admin`'s role will be set to `host_app_user` on login.

Note though that `db_admin` must be a member of `host_app_user`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no.  But you could do this:

```
grant db_admin to host_app_user;
```

Then `host_app_user` will have all the permissions that `db_admin` has.

Comment: But I want `db_admin` to have all the permissions that `host_app_user` has. Both are `superuser`